# Why do uniform, strong and weak convergence coincide for finite dimensional vector spaces?

Tags: linear-algebra, convergence-divergence, vector-spaces

For linear operators $A_n$, $A$ in a finite dimensional vector space $V$, I am trying to prove the equivalence of

1. $\|A_n - A\| = \sup_{x \in \mathbb{C}^n, |x| = 1} |A_nx-Ax| \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$  (Uniform Convergence; henceforth UC)
2. $\forall x\in V: $ $|A_n x - Ax| \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$ (Strong Convergence; henceforth SC)
3. $\forall x, y \in V: |\langle A_n x, y \rangle - \langle Ax, y \rangle | \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$ (Weak Convergence; henceforth WC)

I can show

1. $(UC) \implies (SC)$: Let $x \in V$. Then $ x = \lambda y$ for $\lambda \in \mathbb{F}$ and $y \in V$ s.t. $|y| = 1$. Thus
   \begin{eqnarray*}
   |A_n x - Ax| = \lambda|A_n y - Ay|\leq \lambda\|A_n - A\| \to 0.
   \end{eqnarray*}
2. $(SC) \implies (WC)$: by Cauchy-Schwarz,
   \begin{eqnarray*}
   |\langle A_n x, y \rangle - \langle Ax, y\rangle| = |\langle (A_n-A) x, y \rangle | \leq \langle (A_n-A)x, (A_n-A)x \rangle \langle y, y \rangle = |A_n x - Ax| \cdot |y| \to 0.
   \end{eqnarray*}

To establish equivalence, I also need $(WC) \implies (UC)$, but right now I have no clue how to show this. In particular, I assume I need to use finite-dimensionality somehow, but am not sure how.

Comment: Hint: Without loss of generality assume $A_n$ is matrix and $A=0$. From (WC) follows that for any $\epsilon > 0$ each component of $A_n$ is eventually bounded by $\epsilon$. That is, $A_n$ converges pointwise to $0$. Now, two norms on the space of matrices are equivalent. Thus, we obtain (UC).

Comment: That makes sense :) Do you have a reference for the proof that any two norms on the spaces of matrices are equivalent? (Hadn't covered that yet).

Comment: two norms on a finite dimensional vector space are equivalent. should be in any analysis or calculus book. I am not sure whether it has name.

Comment: usually, it is discussed after compactness and Heine Borel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Pulling down @user251257's comments.*

---

Hint: Without loss of generality assume $A_n$ is a matrix and $A = 0$. From (WC) it follows that for any $\epsilon > 0$ each component of $A_n$ is eventually bounded by $\epsilon$. That is, $A_n$ converges pointwise to $0$. Now, [any two norms on a finite dimensional vector space are equivalent](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/599824/279515). Thus, we obtain (UC).