# There exists M such that $M||\textbf{x}||_{\infty} \le ||\textbf{x}||$

Tags: metric-spaces, normed-spaces

Show there exists M such that $M||\textbf{x}||_{\infty} \le ||\textbf{x}||$.

M positive constant, $||\circ||_{\infty}$ uniform norm, and $||\circ||$ a norm on $\mathbb{R}^m$.

Comment: on $\mathbb{R}^m$. i just amended the question

Comment: This is the usual equivalence of norms in finite-dimensional vector spaces. See for example https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/599824/any-two-norms-on-finite-dimensional-space-are-equivalent?

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\norm}[1]{\Vert #1 \Vert}$
If $\Vert \cdot \Vert$ is an Euclidean norm $\Vert \cdot \Vert_2$,
$$\norm{x} _\infty = \max_{1\leq i \leq m} |x_i|
\leq
\sqrt{x_1^2 + \cdots + x_m^2}
=
\norm{x}_2
$$
Therefore, $M = 1$ will suffice in this case.

Comment: @casper54 did not say that $\lVert . \rVert$ was the Euclidean norm on $\mathbb{R}^{m}$.

Comment: @v_lentin I edited the answer.